# File transfer between Android 6.0 and Windows 7

Tags: windows, file-transfer, 6.0-marshmallow

I updated my Nexus 5 phone to Android 6.0. After this, I have file sync problem between Android 6.0 and Windows 7.

I transferred files from Windows to Android `Internal storage\Download` using USB MTP, then I can see and open the files in Android phone, but cannot see them in `Internal storage\Download` from Windows explorer. I deleted an old file from Android phone, but Windows still gets old list of `Internal storage\Download`.

Even worse, my old photos in the phone cannot be transferred to computer via USB. They do not show up in computers in either Mediafile Transfer mode or Photo transfer mode. Only new photos after update can be shown and transferred.